# Understanding solution to op amp in first order circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

http://www.scribd.com/doc/33828848/Fundamentals-of-Electric-Circuits-Alexander-Sadiku-Chapter-07-Solution-Manual

**Problem 67:**

I'm working on a homework assignment and have solved all of the problems successfully except this one, so I checked the above link to see if i couldn't work out my error, but I'm missing it.

When I solved, I saw that it was a follower, so set my V(t) to be 5, and v->INF to be 0, since the cap should be drained by the time the sun explodes. Safe bet. Then I said that the Req for the capacitor at t>0 was 20 kohms, so the time constant is $$20 * 10^3 * 1 * 10^{-6} = 20/1000 = 20 mS$$

Given $$v(t) = V(inf) + [V(0) - V(inf)]e^{t/T}$$
I get $$v(t) = 5e^{-50t}$$

The solution is using Kirchoff's Current Law to find ... something? it also multiplies by the unit step function for reasons I fail to comprehend...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it also multiplies by the unit step function for reasons I fail to
>   comprehend...

The problem asks that you give the solution for \$t \gt 0\$ but that still doesn't quite explain the presence of \$u(t)\$ in the solution.  I think you would be fine if you don't have the \$u(t)\$ term as long as you indicate the solution is for \$t \gt 0\$.

> The solution is using Kirchoff's Current Law to find ... something?

To find the voltage at node 1, the common connection of the three resistors.  Knowing \$v_1\$ allows you to find the current through the capacitor via the series resistor thus

$$i_C = \frac{v_1 - v_O}{R}$$

You now have the voltage across and the current through the capacitor so, using the capacitor equation

$$C \frac{dv_O}{dt} = i_C =  \frac{v_1 - v_0}{R}$$

you can write the differential equation to solve for \$v_O(t)\$

Now, you *can* go *directly* to the solution for a 1st order RC circuit *if* you know the time constant and, for that, you must find the equivalent resistance of the circuit connected to the capacitor.

The twist here is that you have a dependent source to deal with - the output of the opamp - so you must be careful in setting up the calculation for the equivalent resistance.

It's straightforward to show that the equivalent resistance is \$3R\$

Comment: I ... think I see my error, not treating the op amp's output as a dependent source, which it obviously is. Thanks Alfred.